# Magento newsletter subscribe does not display success or error messages

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to put a newsletter subscription in the footer of a new site, I have it displaying and posting but:

- it does not redirect to a success page
- it does send the confirmation notice
- unverified subscribers do show up in the admin
- clicking on the verification link in the email just goes to the magento home page but does confirm the subscription.
- switching the theme back to default works [notices and success url work]

I'm placing the form in the footer using local.xml:

```
<reference name="footer">
     <block 
          type="newsletter/subscribe"
          name="newsletter" 
          template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

The actual form is the default magento newsletter form with no changes.

1. How do I get it to show success & error messages on both subscription attempts AND on mail confirmation?
2. How do I get the confirmation link [in the email] to go to another page in magento other than the home page i.e. a success page or error page?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in this method `\Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController::newAction` (which is called on this action)

1. You should check where actually in this method you end up. The best way would be to use debugger and set a breakpoint at the beginning of this method. Alternative way would be to use `Mage::log` as logging mechanism, so you can see where do you end up and why messages doesn't show. As I can see there are multiple outputs for session messages, like here `$session->addSuccess($this->__('Confirmation request has been sent.'));`
2. This function is used to redirect to the page that the request came from:`$this->_redirectReferer();`

You can replace that method call with `$this->_redirectUrl($some_url);`

Also, if you are overwriting some of the core files, it is always advisable to copy that file (with module structure) to `app/code/local/`, in order to keep Magento version maintainable.